# ControllerAdvice not work correctly in ConstraintValidator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a custom validation for amount property in request body
and if failed validation its throw my BadRequestException (extend from my BaseException)
and in ExceptionTranslator class (marked with @ControllerAdvice) i have two method for catch exceptions, one for BaseException and other one for RuntimeException
my problem is when validation failed i expect handleBaseException invoked but handleRuntimeException invoked with message Unexpected exception during isValid call.

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        if (value < appConfig.getMinAmount()) {

            throw new BadRequestException()
                    .addErrorDetail(null, I18nKey.EXCEPTION.AMOUNT_SIZE, appConfig.getMinAmount());

        }

        return true;
    }
```

```
public class BadRequestException extends BaseException {

    public BadRequestException() {
        super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {BaseException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBaseException(BaseException ex) {

        //Some work
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {RuntimeException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex) {

        //Some work

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many situations where you can apply a custom validation correctly:

When dealing with DTO validation, you must annotate the request body received in the request with `@Validated`.

On the custom validator, the thrown exception will be `MethodArgumentNotValidException` if some constraints violated (verifications on some fields) or an exception `ConstraintViolationException` on your case, this is the exception that will be thrown not the **BaseException**.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> onConstraintValidationException(
        final MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpServletRequest request) {...}
```

So, the **BaseException** will be within a **ConstraintViolationException** catched by the controller at the point :

`@ExceptionHandler(value = {RuntimeException.class})`